# How to get consecutive colour using gradient node on joined object

Tags: node-editor

I have joined the spheres as one object, and added a gradient texture and colour ramp with 3 colour transitions ( blue, Orange, Red). I'm playing around with the Rotation in the mapping node, but its making a slight angle, and also not treating it as one object, rather on every sphere, if I don't play around with the rotations, each individual sphere has three colours as the colour gradient.

On the right had side I have made squares, not joined and applying each colour separately. that's the effect I want to achieve but using the colorramp node.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would consider using an Empty object as the coordinates input for this material. It will give you way more control over the look you want, just by scaling and rotating the empty in the viewport. Much more intuitive.

[image]

Comment: Just WOW, never seen this on any tutorial before, worked amazing, thanks a lot!